# Where does a dynamodb2 batch begin and end?

Tags: python, batch-processing, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to move my python code from using `dynamodb` to `dynamodb2` to have access to the global secondary index capability. One concept that to me is a lot less clear in `ddb2` compared to `ddb` is that of a batch. Here's once version of my new code which was basically modified from my original `ddb` code:

```
item_pIds = []
batch = table.batch_write()
count = 0
while True:
   m = inq.read()
   count = count + 1
   mStr = json.dumps(m)
   pid = m['primaryId']
   if pid in item_pIds:
       print "pid=%d already exists in the batch, ignoring" % pid
       continue
   item_pIds.append(pid)
   sid = m['secondaryId']
   item_data = {"primaryId" : pid, "secondaryId"] : sid, "message"] : mStr}
   batch.put_item(data=item_data)

   if count >= 25:
       batch = table.batch_write()
       count = 0
       item_pIds = []
```

So what I am doing here is I am getting (JSON) messages from a queue. Each message has a `primaryId` and a `secondaryId`. The `secondaryId` is not unique in that I might get several messages at about the same time that have the same. The `primaryId` is sort of unique. That is, if I get a set of messages at about the same time that have the same `primaryId`, it's bad. However, from time to time, say once in a few hours I may get a message that need to override an existing message with the same `primaryId`. So this seems to align well with the statement from the `dynamodb2` [**documentation page**](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html) similar to that of `ddb`:

> DynamoDB’s maximum batch size is 25 items per request. If you attempt to put/delete more than that, the context manager will batch as many as it can up to that number, then flush them to DynamoDB and continue *batching* as more calls come in.

However, what I noticed is that a large chunk of messages that I get through the queue never make it to the database. That is, when I try to retrieve them later, they are not there. So I was told that a better way of handling batch writes is by doing something like this:

```
with table.batch_write() as batch:
   while True:
        m = inq.read()
        mStr = json.dumps(m)
        pid = m['primaryId']
        sid = m['secondaryId']
        item_data = {"primaryId" : pid, "secondaryId"] : sid, "message"] : mStr}
        batch.put_item(data=item_data)
```

That is, I only call `batch_write()` once similar to how I would open a file only once and then write into it continuously. But in this case, I don't understand what the "rule of 25 max" means. When does a batch start and end? And how do I check for duplicate `primaryId`s? That is, remembering *all* messages that I ever received through the queue is not realistic since (i) I have too many of them (the system runs 24/7) and (ii) as I stated before, occasional repeated ids are OK.

Sorry for the long message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *batch* will start whenever the request is sent and end when the last request in the batch is completed.

As with any [RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming), every request comes with a *cost*, meaning how much/many resources it will take to complete said request. With the `batch_write()` class in DynamoDB2, they are *wrapping* the requests in a group and creating a *queue* to process them, which will reduce the cost as they are no longer individual requests.

The `batch_write()` class returns a context manager that handles the individual requests and what you get back slightly resembles a `Table` object but only has the `put_item` and `delete_item` requests.

DynamoDB's max batch size is 25, just like you've read. From the comments in the [source code](http://pydoc.net/Python/boto/2.9.3/boto.dynamodb2.table/):

> DynamoDB's maximum batch size is 25 items per request. If you attempt
>   to put/delete more than that, the context manager will batch as many
>   as it can up to that number, then flush them to DynamoDB & continue
>   batching as more calls come in.

You can also read about migrating, batches in particular, from DynamoDB to DynamoDB2 [here](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrations/dynamodb_v1_to_v2.html#batch-writes).